# (Pywinauto) How to connect to new window when you dont know its name

Tags: python, pywinauto

Im doing automation for a chat application on windows by module Pywinauto in python. When i create a new chat room, it generated a new window with unfixed name of window. The window name depends on numbers of chat room members. Example : if there are two members, chat room name displayed as name of that two members. But if there are more than 5 members, chat room name will be showns as member x and 4 others.

So the windows name is always changed. I dont know how to connect the new window to perform action

Im using Desktop(backend ='uia')
Backend win32 is also too

(SOLVED)
I walkaround and found a solution for this.
Step1:  connect to mainwindow (app = Application(backend ='uia').connect(title = mainwindowapp)

Step2: get top window ( app.top_window() )

Answer (score 2):

If this new window is in the same process, it's better to use `Application(backend="uia").connect(process=pid)` where you can get `pid` from main window by method `.process_id()`. Then you can get all top level windows of this process:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

pid = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Main Window Title").process_id()
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=pid)
top_windows_before = app.windows()
# do some actions (create new chat)
for w in app.windows():
    if w not in top_windows_before:
        new_chat = w
```

Comparison between wrapper objects should work, that's why I suggest boolean operator `w not in top_windows_before`.